# Content Porter 2009 SP1 with 5.3 SP1 -- Errors on Export when multiple parent publications

Tags: tridion

I've worked my way down the blueprint and found that the issue begins when trying to export a publication ("06 Structure") that has more than one parent.

> 5/2/2012 5:08:16 PM    [Error] Failed to export item '/webdav/06 Structure 1.0/Building Blocks/System/Page Templates'
>   5/2/2012 5:08:16 PM [Error] (TCMDAL::ExecuteRequest:Content Manager returned an error)  
>   5/2/2012 5:08:16 PM [Error] (TCMDAL::Communications::CheckResponseForErrors)  Errors encountered during check of response
>   5/2/2012 5:08:16 PM [Error] (TCMDAL::Communications::ExecuteRequest)  Error while executing request
>   5/2/2012 5:08:16 PM [Error] (TCMDAL::TCMItem::Read)  Error while reading item '/webdav/06 Structure 1.0/Building Blocks/System/Page Templates'

The parent publication priorities for "06 Structure" are:

```
1.  "04 Content Freezer"
2.  "04 Content" (note this is also a parent of "04 Content Freezer", if that has any relevance)
3.  "04 Design" (note this is the publication that the "Page Templates" items would come from)
```

I've applied the hotfix 75095 to the Content Porter Server, but it seems that the hotfix doesn't address this particular issue, though conceptually, it seems similar.

Comment: Are any items created in the export package before the error is thrown? Also are there any other errors in the event logs of SDL Tridion?

Comment: No, none of the items are exported.  I was thinking maybe the issue didn't begin until after dependencies had finished resolving.

Comment: Attempted export of 1 page

[Error] Failed to export item '/webdav/07 Site - US 2.0/Building Blocks/System/Page Templates'
4/27/2012 6:44:38 PM [Error] (TCMDAL::ExecuteRequest:Content Manager returned an error)  <no description>
4/27/2012 6:44:38 PM [Error] (TCMDAL::Communications::CheckResponseForErrors)  Errors encountered during check of response
4/27/2012 6:44:38 PM [Error] (TCMDAL::Communications::ExecuteRequest)  Error while executing request
4/27/2012 6:44:38 PM [Error] (TCMDAL::TCMItem::Read)  Error while reading item '/webdav/07 Site - US 2.0/Building Blocks/System/Page Templates'

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Chris mentioned, look in the Windows server logs - "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" is a generic error that could cover a lot of issues.

Does the error occur if you run the CP client from the server itself?

Comment: Yes, I tried running it directed from the server and had the same problem.  That's where I got the message I posted above

Comment: You'll need to poke around the server logs - Tridion, TCM, Application, System. Could be a COM+ issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've seen no errors reported on the server in any of those areas.

Comment: Can you get to /06 Structure 1.0/Building Blocks/System/Page Templates in the GUI with no issues?

If you can, you may need to contact support and let them review your DB.